# Error linking sqlite C

Tags: c, sqlite

I'm trying to use sqlite with C. It's really easy in Python to do this, but when I try to do the same with C, I get an error.

I found this:

[libsqlite in simulator and iOS compiling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7622610/libsqlite-in-simulator-and-ios-compiling/7623043#7623043)

but I am simply using a text editor, so I cannot use XCode (well, I could, but I'm not). When I do

```
#include <sqlite.h> // or "sqlite.h"
```

I get an error like so:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_open", referenced from:
      _main in ccb8OLfK.o
  "_sqlite3_exec", referenced from:
      _main in ccb8OLfK.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

If you want to look at my code, here's all of it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <sqlite3.h>

#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    /* variables */
    // create value for storing return codes
    int retval;

    // the number of queries to be handled
    int qnum;

    // size of each query
    int qsize;

    // pointer
    int ind;

    // statement for fetching tables
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;

    // pointer to sqlite3
    sqlite3 *db;

    // db name
    char *home = getenv("HOME");
    char *dbPath = strcat(home, "/Desktop/test.db");

    /* connect and write */
    // Try to connect to database (if fails, returns null)
    retval = sqlite3_open(dbPath, &db);
    if (retval) {
        printf("\x1B[31;1mConnection failed.\x1B[0m\n");
        exit(1);
    } else {
        printf("\x1B[32;1mConnected to Database.\x1B[0m\n");
    }

    // create table
    char q[100] = "create table if not exists test (user text not null, psswd text not null);";
    retval = sqlite3_exec(db, q, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

It has a couple unused variables so far and only creates a table (if I could get that far), but it should compile and run fine.

I'm new to C (Java --> Python --> C). How do I get this to work?

This seems like a really big pain, so could I just download the header file for sqlite3 (I wouldn't know from where though) and include it with quotes? I don't know how to link a file, and I would just like this preliminary test to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to also download the sqlite3 source code and compile it with your application. The header only provides information about the functions; the sqlite3 source code (the "amalgamation" is recommended) provides the actual implementations, which is what the linker wants.

Comment: Alright, I just did that with homebrew. That should work right? ...There's a sqlite.h in the sqlite dir in Homebrew's Cellar (/usr/local/Cellar/).

Comment: In that case, yeah, just link with `-lsqlite3` or include the library in Xcode. (AFAIK Xcode should actually have sqlite3 support as part of CoreData, but I haven't touched that part of iOS yet)

Comment: Like I said, I'm not using Xcode... I'm just using a text editor. I put the header in the same directory, but I have no idea what to do with it. I'm going to have to retire for the night. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Dylan, the header file just tells the compiler what functions you will be using, it doesn't make them available for use. To make them available for use, you must also have installed `libsqlite3` and it must be installed in your normal library search path. Then you compile with `gcc .... -lsqlite3` to include the actual code for the functions in your app.